# Notification manager has stopped working

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

**This issue has been solved.  See my solution below.**

I just completed converting my messaging app to FCM. You can see the process I have been through [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031948/fcm-returning-mismatchsenderid). Now that it is done, my notifications no longer work.  If my FirebaseMessagingService gets a message and the main app is not active, I create a notification on the phone I'm running on.

This has been running for years correctly on GCM.  When I trace through the code, it all executes ok - just no notification shows up in the tray.  I can't imagine what Firebase would have to do with this.

This is the code that gets called from the FirebaseMessagingService.  This code has been running for years just fine . . .

```
public static void raiseNotification( String username, String mesText, int count)
{
    String message = "From: " + username + " " + mesText;
    if (count > 1)
    {
        count--;
        message = message +  " + " + count + " more";
    }



    NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(GlobalStuff.GCT);

    Intent intent = new Intent(GlobalStuff.GCT, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("whattodo", username);
    intent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis())); //just to make it unique from the next one
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(GlobalStuff.GCT, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


    b.setContentTitle("New SafeTalk Message")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ticon)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setTicker("New SafeTalk Message")
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    //.addAction(R.drawable.smallredball, "Read Now", pIntent)
    //.addAction(R.drawable.smallquestion, "hello there", pIntent);

    NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager)GlobalStuff.GCT.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mgr.notify(0, b.build());
}
```

Comment: You can't just swap FCM for GCM and expect it to work. There is a lot you have to do to migrate to FCM...Where is your `onMessageReceived` method? Your example code is not enough to identify your issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031948/fcm-returning-mismatchsenderid pretty much explains what I have done.  It's really quite a bit of work.

Comment: So where is `raiseNotification` being called?

Comment: From my extention of FirebaseMessagingService.  Used to be called from an intent service.  I've traced it through and the mgr.notify is getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved. Once you write an app for Android, Google will have you working full time for the rest of your life just to keep it working.  **They are breaking change demons**.  Turns out this notification problem has nothing to do with Firebase (which is itself the mother of all breaking changes).

Google changed the requirements on how to send a notification in Oreo.  Google designed this change so that if your app is running on Oreo and you haven't made the change your notification simply won't work - hope nobody was building notifications that were important.  In Oreo they require a channelId.

Here is code that works in Oreo . . .

**Actually this code does not completely work in Oreo. See my next post regarding notifications in Oreo**

```
   private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```